Server 403 when I try to get video by direct link
I am writing a software for downloading videos from a website. I found a direct link (https://video.sibnet.ru/v/24b1b8b0733c192f76dc6e32bafbd109/4108163.mp4) to download video through HTML markup on the site (https://animejoy.ru/tv-serialy/2341-zakazyvali-krolika-3-sezon.html). When I click the link, the server returns 403 Forbidden. Why can I watch the video through the player on the site, but can't access it directly?

"I found a direct link [...] to download video through HTML markup on the site" - checking in the network panel, the request for that URL on the actual site gets redirected to //dv98.sibnet.ru/37/74/79/3774793.mp4?st=8BZoNwTTJbifHfvCT-q4bw&e=1717014000&stor=7&noip=1 - and those additional parameters are probably needed, to be able to actually get the content, and not a 403 response. Those parameters might be based on the IP address of the site visitor, or correspond to something stored in a cookie ...

you need the Referer header, set it to https://video.sibnet.ru/

@CBroe Why does server return 302 and redirects to a valid URL when request is from the website and returns 403 when done manually?
